# Upgraded to Windows 10, username not displayed on lock screen

Tags: windows-10

My work PC was upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10 using the Microsoft upgrade wizard, which preserved all my apps and settings.

This worked surprisingly well, everything runs as it should. However, the Windows lock screen is not showing my user picture or user name. Every other environment I connect to shows my user name, apart from my own. The only difference AFAIK, is that my PC was upgraded, and all other environments were installed from scratch.

[image: Lock screen]

I did some googling, and found a couple of group policy settings that could be tweaked, but nothing has made any difference. The settings I tried are:

- Interactive logon: Display user information when the session is locked = `User display name, domain and user names`
- Interactive logon: Don't display last signed-in = `Disabled`
- Interactive logon: Don't display username at sign-in = `Disabled`

[image: Group policy editor]

Does anyone have any other suggestions I could try?

Other info in case it is pertinent:

- I log in with my domain user account, which has local admin rights on my PC.
- I connect to it using RDP over a VPN, from a Windows 10 PC at home.

### Updates

I tried setting `Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Logon\Hide entry points for Fast User Switching` = `Enabled` in group policy. This made no difference.

I tried to change my account name, but since it is a domain account, there is no way to change it on my PC. The only thing I can change is my account photo. I tried changing the photo. The photo is correctly shown in the Start menu and in the Settings UI, but is still not shown on the lock screen.

Comment: What are these other environments running?  Windows 10 logon screen was changed significantly.

Comment: My Windows 10 PC at home shows my user name on the lock screen. The other environments I connect to at work are a mixture of Windows Server 2008 R2, 2012 R2, 2016 and 2019, and they all show my user name on the lock screen too.

Comment: Try to change your settings for [Enable/Disable Fast User Switching](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/95383-enable-disable-fast-user-switching-windows-10-a.html). Renaming your account might help in *Control Panel > User Accounts > Change your account name*.